# Pandas Float Precision - Apparently Identical Numbers Showing as Not Equal

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, boolean, precision

Hopefully a very simple solution to this. I have tried the solutions for two similar questions on SO, but these haven't worked for me.

Essentially I have a process which evaluates whether numbers in two columns of a dataframe are equal or not. For the vast majority this appears correct. However, in a very small number of cases, seemingly equal numbers are showing (to 6 decimal places) as not equal.

Clearly this is down to how my numbers are stored vs what I am seeing. But bizarrely, the data source of these numbers only stores them as 6dp, and trying to increase display.precision doesn't have any effect - I still only see 6dp.

```
a=df[df['Timestamp']=='2018-03-04 22:29:57']['Limit'].copy()

b=df[df['Timestamp']=='2018-03-04 22:29:57']['Quote'].copy()

pd.options.display.precision
Out[152]: 10

a
Out[153]: 
15571027   25.850000
Name: Limit, dtype: float64

b
Out[154]: 
15571027   25.850000
Name: Quote, dtype: float64

a==b
Out[155]: 
15571027    False
dtype: bool

a-b
Out[156]: 
15571027   -0.000000
dtype: float64

b>a
Out[157]: 
15571027    True
dtype: bool
```

I am hoping some kind soul might be able to suggest the next logical steps I could try here - clearly b is greater than a, but 1) I cannot display this, and 2) I would ultimately like to create boolean comparisons which I know will be accurate to the same precision as I am displaying.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: try rounding your data to the precision you display, if that's fine for you

Comment: Yes that would make sense. But I'd really like to understand a bit more about how my floats are being stored, and why the boolean comparison is producing an unexpected result here.

Comment: please check: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: "seemingly equal numbers" --> Print float64 to 17 _significant_ digits to see if they are equal.  6 places of _absolute/fixed_ precision is not certainly enough.

Comment: Similar/identical issue: [Running the same script on the same pandas data produces very slightly different dataframe floating-point values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70879612/running-the-same-script-on-the-same-data-produces-very-slightly-different-datafr)

Comment: Assuming this is the same root-cause [pandas 1.2.0: Change in default floating precision for `read_csv` and `read_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.2.0.html#change-in-default-floating-precision-for-read-csv-and-read-table) a) Always state your pandas and Python versions b) Please try to add an MCVE example, to make this reproducible. Currently noone other than you can reproduce this. c) Well was your float data coming in from read_csv/read_table? or else how? Please show two float values. Check their representation up to 17dps.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I found the root of the problem.

Initially, all of these numbers were identical as floats at the start of the process, then by the end a handful of numbers had somehow been altered as floats, even though they hadn't changed in terms of how they were displayed.

The culprit was joining them via a large SQLite operation within pandas - there was too much data to attempt to merge, so they were imported as tables, joined as needed, and written back out as a dataframe. Even though no numbers were actally altered (ie by division / aggregation etc), it was during this process that the stored definition of some of the floats were altered.

Thanks @Artyom Akselrod for the education - by implicitly rounding the output in the SELECT statement, this sorted the problem.