# Running the same script on the same pandas data produces very slightly different dataframes floating-point values

Tags: python, pandas, csv, floating-point, precision

I am executing a script that I have run before on the same data. The dataframe I get is only so slightly different than the previous one (in the 10th decimal point or so). For example:

- in some column (and row) the old dataframe contains the price 5673391.88.
- In the same column and same row of the new dataframe the value seems to be exactly the same (5673391.88).
- However if I subtract the two columns I get a difference of -9.445123e-10.

This is of course the case for the entire column, not just the particular row. How can that be? Please note that I cannot confirm same environment (pandas or Python version) between the two script runs. Can it be one of these two reasons? Something else?

Comment: Tell us the approximate pandas and Python versions, or at least install dates. Especilly when you're reporting this sort of issue.

Comment: Also I added 'pandas' and 'floating-point' to your title. The original title wording was very vague. It could have been any of a thousand packages.

Comment: How are you subtracting them from each other?  Where did you store the data from the old script the last time you ran it?  How are you retrieving it etc. etc.  could be any of those steps where the rounding went wonky!

Comment: Similar/identical issue: [Pandas Float Precision - Apparently Identical Numbers Showing as Not Equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65680753/pandas-float-precision-apparently-identical-numbers-showing-as-not-equal)

Comment: @smci Python should not be very different, maybe not at all, like 3.6 and 3.7. But for Pandas I am really not sure, could have been 0.25 in the first and >1.2.0 in the second. So, taking into account the answer below, this could indeed be the issue right? Interesting...

Comment: @ JeffUK the data is stored locally in a folder (Windows) and retrieved using Jupyterlab and pandas read_csv function. To subtract I merge the two dataframes on common columns and then just subtract the respective columns in the merged df

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason: [`Pandas 1.2.0` which was released back in `26 Dec 2020`, they have highlighted this issue](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.2.0.html#change-in-default-floating-precision-for-read-csv-and-read-table):

> #### *Change in default floating precision for read_csv and read_table*
>
> *the methods `read_csv()` and `read_table()` could read `floating point` numbers slightly incorrectly with respect to the last bit in precision.*

Before this version `floating_precision="high"` has always been available to avoid this issue.

But, within this version the default is now `floating_precision=None` to make precision more acurate. It won't have any impact on performance.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work in my case. So I read the newly produced dataframe with floating_precision = 'High' or 'legacy' or 'round_trip' but without lack. To be precise, when using 'High' I got the exact same results, when I used the other two I got even more columns different. I will now try to reproduce the dataframe by running all the pipeline that produces it with an older Pandas version. Will update the thread.

Comment: Georgios please try to cook up some reproducible example (MCVE) and post it, otherwise noone can reproduce your anecdotal results. Also, in your script please automatically log the versions of pandas, Python, numpy, and every other package that's being used in your pipeline that could be affecting this. Beware of taking constant package updates, for reproducibility. Use virtual environments to have multiple versions in parallel.